# Is this system invertible or not?

Tags: linear-systems, homework, inverse-problem, inverse

> Prove that the following system is invertible.
>
> $$y(t) = \mathcal{T}\{x(t)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{3t} x(\tau) \,\mathrm d \tau$$

Answer: yes, the system is invertible. I need some hint here, not the full solution.

Comment: i have tried Differentiation but there are limits that giving me problems.

Comment: That's right, so basicaly you have a problem with differentiating an integral with respect to its variable limits ?

Comment: Yes that's right. I think i have to revise Calculus little bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its intuitive to differentiate the given I/O integral:

$$y(t) = \mathcal{T}\{x(t)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{3t} x(\tau) d\tau$$

you can make this (unnecessary) little change before
$$y(t/3) = \int_{-\infty}^{t} x(\tau) d\tau$$

and then, differentiate both sides:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left( y(t/3) \right) = \frac{d}{dt} \int_{-\infty}^{t} x(\tau) d\tau $$

yielding
$$ \frac{1}{3} y(t/3)^{'} = x(t) $$, or stated better $$x(t) = T_i\{y(t)\} = \frac{1}{3} y(t/3)^{'}$$ as the inverse system.

Note: differentiation of an integral with variable limits is known as the **Leibnitz Rule** :

given
$$F(x) = \int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)} g(x,t) dt$$
then
$$ \frac{d}{dx} F(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)} g(x,t) dt $$
$$ F'(x) = g(x,\beta(x)) \beta'(x) - g(x,\alpha(x)) \alpha'(x) +  \int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)} \frac{d}{dx} g(x,t) dt$$

Comment: Dude why are you so Intelligent i mean you have answer to every question